# How to inherit from multiple CWindowImpl-derived classes

Tags: c++, winapi, multiple-inheritance, atl

Is it possible to create a class that derives from two or more `CWindowImpl`-derived classes?  Maybe with virtual inheritance?  I was trying to do something like this, in order to take advantage of `CHAIN_MSG_MAP`:

```
class CClassOne : public virtual CWindowImpl<CClassOne>
{
public:

BEGIN_MSG_MAP(CClassOne)
    // ...
END_MSG_MAP()

}

class CClassTwo : public virtual CWindowImpl<CClassTwo>
{
public:

BEGIN_MSG_MAP(CClassTwo)
    // ...
END_MSG_MAP()

}

class CClassThree : public CClassOne, public CClassTwo
{
public:

BEGIN_MSG_MAP(CClassThree)
    CHAIN_MSG_MAP(CClassOne)
    CHAIN_MSG_MAP(CClassTwo)
END_MSG_MAP()

}
```

But when I instantiate CClassThree and try to call `SubclassWindow`, I get an ambiguous-access compilation error.  So does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to inherit from 2+ `CWindowImpl` bases (and it does not make much sense overall too). Instead, as you have more choices for your message map in [Message Map Macros (ATL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/message-map-macros-atl?view=msvc-160), you would prefer to have separate classes with message map referencing them via `CHAIN_MSG_MAP_MEMBER` or have a composite control with chaining to multiple members, for example (depending on relation between your windows, whether they are peers or parent/child ones).

Comment: Okay, thanks.  The thing I don't like about `CHAIN_MSG_MAP_MEMBER` is that if the chained member procedure does something to its `m_hWnd`, then I guess you have to explicitly set its `m_hWnd` to the parent class's `m_hWnd` in order for it to work.  Isn't that right?

Comment: It depends on how you structure your code, you can find some good examples, [like this](https://github.com/trieck/pixievm/blob/63fab535515cedabbe72a8a75a76768c02812fda/pxemu/pxemuView.h).

Comment: IIRC the rule of thumb is that with `_MEMBER` you can chain processing to member with a separate map. Then `_ALT` versions let you combine handlers for different windows within one map. You can have the combination of those to structure your code in desired way. Then remember these are all just macros, so you can look the implementation up and customize that even further.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/dinodragon/mygooglecode/blob/1a5525ec6ef1b88f94af55a101d520e1aab83100/QuickStart/ATLWindow/CWindowImplDemo/MainWindow.cpp#L25) might be a better example because both are real windows with separate real handles, as opposed to just handler maps in the link above.